# How do I track down a leak?

Tags: water-leak

During rain, you can feel a small drip on your feet on the passenger side of my 97 Subaru Legacy. How do I find the source of the leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a friend to spray water on the windshield and surrounding areas while you are inside the car doors closed with a flashlight looking under the dash. Don't spray the water forcibly at the windshield try to make it like a rain shower. You can make a simple stand out of pump pipe holding a shower head to do the same thing if you don't have an assistant.

Comment: Also note traces that water left from previous times it leaked. Usually water could be from ventilation or if your windscreen frame has rusted under the window sealing.